# React hook "useSelector" is called in function error for my permissions context provider

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a permissions provider that wraps some `react-redux` global state. I have as follows:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

export const PermissionsContext = React.createContext();

const getUserAbilities = createSelector(
  state => state.user.abilities,
  abilities =>
    abilities.reduce((acc, val) => {
      acc[val] = true;
      return acc;
    }, {})
);

function useAbilities() {
  const abilities = useSelector(getUserAbilities);
  return { abilities };
}

export const PermissionsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { abilities } = useAbilities();
  const can = useCallback((...permissions) => permissions.every(permission => permission in abilities), [
    abilities
  ]);
  return <PermissionsContext.Provider value={{ can }}>{children}</PermissionsContext.Provider>;
};

export const withPermissions = WrappedComponent => {
  return class ComponentWithPermissions extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <PermissionsContext.Consumer>
          {props => <WrappedComponent {...this.props} permissions={props} />}
        </PermissionsContext.Consumer>
      );
    }
  };
};
```

Usage of `PermissionsProvider`:

```
<PermissionsProvider>
    <App />
</PermissionsProvider>
```

This includes a context so I can `useContext(PermissionsContext)` and also a HOC `withPermissions` so that I wrap legacy `class` components with it.

In the case of a `class`, I would call `this.props.permissions.can('doThing1', 'doThing2')` and it should return `true` or `false` depending on whether all of those abilities are present in the user payload.

It seems to be functioning fine except when I try to commit it, I get the error:

> React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "can" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

I saw a few issues with naming convention, but that doesn't seem to apply here(?). I also used to have the `useAbilities` hook inside the function just above the `can` function which also threw the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: value={{ can }} === value={{ can: can }} ==> value is getting an object with a can property. is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above code was correct. It seemed to be some sort of eslint cache that was continuing to complain. After clearing cache and rerunning lint it went away.